# Code is working properly only with alert. Commenting alert its giving

Tags: javascript

Need help with below code. This code should work without any alert. But its malfunctioning. When uncomment alert its working as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10">
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .gallery {
      position: relative;
      background: rgba(15, 202, 152, 0.2) !important;
      border: 2px solid rgba(15, 202, 152, 0.3) !important;
      padding: .375rem .75rem;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 190px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item {
      position: relative;
      min-height: inherit;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item label {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1;
      color: #0fca98 !important;
      vertical-align: super;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload-container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      min-height: inherit;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload-container h5.hint {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 19px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 19px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload-container h5.hint {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload-container.uploaded h5.hint {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload {
      position: relative;
      min-height: inherit;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba(15, 202, 152, 0.3) !important;
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .upload img {
      width: 95%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .gallery .gallery-item .form-control {
      height: 35px;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: .5rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="blue-skin">

  <div id="main-wrapper">

    <section class="gray-simple pt-3">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="submit-page">
              <div class="form-submit">
                <div class="submit-section">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label>Rooms</label>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                      <select class="form-control" name="bedrooms" id="rooms">
                        <option value="">Choose...</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Gallery -->
              <div class="form-submit">
                <h3>Gallery</h3>
                <div class="submit-section">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                      <label>Upload Gallery</label> <span class="pics"></span>
                      <div class="row gallery">
                        <div class="col-md-3 gallery-item" elemid="img-cphoto">
                          <label>Cover Photo</label>
                          <div class="upload-container">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="d-none" accept="image/png, image/tiff, image/jpeg, image/jpg" required/>
                            <div class="upload">
                              <img src="" id="img-cphoto" class="d-none" />
                            </div>
                            <h5 class="hint"><i class="fa fa-upload text-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload</h5>
                          </div>
                          <input name="title[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Photo Title e.g. Front Pic" required />
                          <input name="img-area[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Covered Area" required />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var start;
      $("#rooms").on('focus', function() {
        start = "";
        start = this.value;
        if (start === "" || start === "NaN") {
          start = 0;
        }
        start = parseInt(start);
      }).change(function() {
        var num;
        num = parseInt(this.value);
        //alert(start);
        // Alert uncomment karne per thik function kar raha hai

        var label = "Room ";
        var lblTxt;
        var elem = "";
        if (start > num) {
          for (let i = start; i > num; i--) {
            var rlbl = $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i));
            $(".gallery-item").each(function(index) {
              var relbl = $(this).attr('elemid');
              console.log(index + ": " + relbl);
              if (relbl === rlbl) {
                $(this).remove();
              }
            });
          }
        }

        if (start < num) {
          for (let i = start; i < num; i++) {
            lblTxt = label + (parseInt(i) + 1);
            elem = '<div class="col-md-3 gallery-item"  elemid="' + $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i) + 1) + '">';
            elem += '<label>' + lblTxt + '</label>';
            elem += '<div class="upload-container">';
            elem += '<input type="file" name="image" class="d-none" accept="image/png, image/tiff, image/jpeg, image/jpg" required/>';
            elem += '<div class="upload">';
            elem += '<img src=""  id="' + $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i) + 1) + '" class="d-none" />';
            elem += '</div>';
            elem += '<h5 class="hint"><i class="fa fa-upload text-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload</h5>'
            elem += '</div>';
            elem += '<input name="title[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Photo Title e.g. Master Bedroom" required />';
            elem += '<input name="img-area[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Carpet Area" required />';
            elem += '</div>';
            $('.gallery').append(elem);
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Request developer members to check this code and help to fix the issue. I have separated this piece of code from large code and checked in separate file named error.html and tested in almost all browsers. Error remains same. Code submitted here is entire code from error.html file.

Looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: Any error mesages in browsers console?

Comment: When you click on an alert message, focus of elements changes, so maybe you expect your `focus` handler to trigger again but it won't without an alert message?

Comment: What *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: What I am expecting with this code. On change of number of rooms it should add image image uploader box to be added. Suppose I select 2 in dropdown. It should add 2 image uploader box, which is working fine. Now if I change number of room to 3 after selecting 2. It should add only 1 image uploader box. But it is again adding another 3, this is the malfunction.  On other hand changing number of rooms from 3 to 1. There should only one place holder left. Which is not happening. But when uncomment //alert(start); code is working as expected. Entire code is written, kindly run once to check.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue with the help of [How to remove focus from input field in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010791/how-to-remove-focus-from-input-field-in-jquery)
Now the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var start;
  $("#rooms").on('focus', function() {
    start = "";
    start = this.value;
    if (start === "" || start === "NaN") {
      start = 0;
    }
    start = parseInt(start);
  }).change(function() {
    var num;
    num = parseInt(this.value);
    //alert(start);
    // Alert uncomment karne per thik function kar raha hai

    var label = "Room ";
    var lblTxt;
    var elem = "";
    if (start > num) {
      for (let i = start; i > num; i--) {
        var rlbl = $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i));
        $(".gallery-item").each(function(index) {
          var relbl = $(this).attr('elemid');
          console.log(index + ": " + relbl);
          if (relbl === rlbl) {
            $(this).remove();
          }
        });
      }
    }

    if (start < num) {
      for (let i = start; i < num; i++) {
        lblTxt = label + (parseInt(i) + 1);
        elem = '<div class="col-md-3 gallery-item"  elemid="' + $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i) + 1) + '">';
        elem += '<label>' + lblTxt + '</label>';
        elem += '<div class="upload-container">';
        elem += '<input type="file" name="image" class="d-none" accept="image/png, image/tiff, image/jpeg, image/jpg" required/>';
        elem += '<div class="upload">';
        elem += '<img src=""  id="' + $.trim(label) + '-' + (parseInt(i) + 1) + '" class="d-none" />';
        elem += '</div>';
        elem += '<h5 class="hint"><i class="fa fa-upload text-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload</h5>'
        elem += '</div>';
        elem += '<input name="title[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Photo Title e.g. Master Bedroom" required />';
        elem += '<input name="img-area[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Carpet Area" required />';
        elem += '</div>';
        $('.gallery').append(elem);
      }
    }
   $("#rooms").blur();
  });
})();
```

I would like to thanks Bergi who drew my attention to focus issue. Now its working as expected.